# Android | NativeScript | Notifications - led, badge, settings

Tags: angular, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am developing mobile application with nativescript and angular on client side and node.js for server.
I am trying to implement push notifications on android platform. I am using firebase plugin - `fcm-node` on backend and `nativescript push notifications` plugin on mobile side.

When I receive new notification the sound and vibration are working but led light not turns on.
In addition I want to show badge counter on app icon at launchers that it is possible.

This is code that runs on server side and set ups settings of notifications.

```
publishNotification(userToken, notification, data, callback) {    
let message = {
    to: userToken,
    notification: {
       title: 'Title',
       body: 'Body',
       message: 'Message',
       sound = 'default',
       color = '#9bcb4d';
       priority = "high";
    },
    data: data
};

FirebasePublisher.fcm.send(message, callback);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some code outlining what you have tried so far.